# Adding SQL for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, read-sql

i am a newbees for programming, i have an db file with some date, open, high, low , close data in it, and name with 0001.HK; 0002.HK; 0003.HK
then i try to build a loop to take out some data in the database.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join('data', "hkprice.db"))


def read_price(stock_id):
    
    connect = 'select Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume from ' + stock_id
    df = pd.read_sql(connect, conn,index_col=['Date'], parse_dates=['Date'])

for y in range(1 ,2):
    read_price(str(y).zfill(4) + '.HK')
```

when it output it show: Execution failed on sql 'select Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume from 0001.HK': unrecognized token: "0001.HK"

but i should have the 0001.HK table in the database
what should i do?

Comment: try adding a `'`around the value you pass, `read_price("'" + str(y).zfill(4) + ".HK'")`

Comment: it works thank you so much!! then and other question...how can i skip the no such table while looping?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? You can just simply add a `try-except` statement specifying error type and let it simply pass in case table doesn't exist.

Comment: @pavel hello sir! thanks for answering me again
I saw someone use `except: pass`(its didn't work), but i find out that i shouldn't loop the file name with number range...
in my sql db, some of the number are not exist, such as 
0012.HK(exist); 0013.HK(not exist); 0014.HK(exist), 
so i think i shouldn't loop with the file name, but i am not sure about how to read the sql one by one

Comment: @y2kmarkham, it's strange, because `except: pass` should work, although it's a very bad habit to use it like this. Instead do `except %ExceptionClass%:` where you replace %ExceptionClass% with the actual class of exception you are getting. Make sure `pass` is on the next line and properly indented.

Comment: it's said `Execution failed on sql 'select Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume from '0013.HK'': no such table: 0013.HK`. i think i should change the way to read the sql..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use variables with a query, you need to put a placeholder `?`. So in your particular case:

```
connect = 'select Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume from ?'
```

After that in `read_sql` you can provide a list of your variables to the `params` kwarg like so:

```
df = pd.read_sql(connect, conn, params=[stock_id], index_col=['Date'], parse_dates=['Date'])
```

If you have multiple parameters and, hence, multiple `?` placeholders then when you supply the list of variables to `params` they need to be in exactly the same order as your `?`.

**EDIT**:
For example if I had a query where I wanted to get data between some dates, this is how I would do it:

```py
start = ['list of dates']
end = ['another list of dates']

query = """select * 
           from table
           where start_date >= ? and
                 end_date < ?
        """

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=[start, end])
```

Here interpreter will see the first `?` and grab the first item from the first list, then when it gets to the second `?` it will grab the first item from the second list. If there's a mismatch between the number of `?` and the number of supplied params then it will throw an  error.

Comment: thank you so much, but i am a bit confused about the placeholder, am i right to putting 'select ... from ' + stock_id ?

Comment: No, you put `?` as a placeholder into your query. Once interpreter reaches the `?` it will look whether anything has been provided to `params` kwarg and if all matches up, it will automatically populate data, otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: @y2kmarkham, see added **EDIT** section in my answer.